# How to convert a value of "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn" to "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn"

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview for showing working or non-working of weekly.
Fisrt, when  i binding with dataset then it choose automatic type to be checkboxColumn because a data from dataset is boolean type like below.

[image]

but I need to change it to be combobox compound with true and false value 
[image]

but it's have a problem because i can't add item "true or false" it error" datagridviewcomboboxcell value is not valid ".
And I don't want to make dataset for store two value.it's waste.

---

Note: I will explain step by step

This is my database for filling in datagridview
[image]

And I use this query for creating "weekly_scheduleTableAdapter"  .It will select  each day and flag(1 or 0)

[image]

```
                SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT  [nonworking_day_flag]
                                 FROM [dbo].[default_nonworking_days]
                                 WHERE [id] =1 ) AS Sun
                               ,
                                 (SELECT  [nonworking_day_flag]
                                  FROM [dbo].[default_nonworking_days]
                                   WHERE [id] =2 ) AS Mon 
                               ,........
                                  ....until Saturday....
                                    ....................
                FROM [dbo].[default_nonworking_days]
```

Result: [image]

After I created "weekly_scheduleTableAdapter" I just binding datagridview to dataset.

[image]

it's can fill data to gridview (See first picture above). But if I need to change a cell to be combobox what should I do? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a check box column to a combo box column.  If you want a combo box column then you have to add a combo box column.  You need to add the column before binding, either in the designer or in code, and set the `DataPropertyName` property of that column to tell it what column of the data source to bind to.  If you want an example of this, [look here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476-NET-2-0-Adding-a-ComboBox-Column-to-a-DataGridView&highlight=).

EDIT: I didn't read your full question in the first place but it seems that you know how to add a column.  You don't have to bind that column to a `DataSet` or `DataTable` or anything else.  You can bind it to a simple collection of custom-made objects if you like or you can even add directly to its `Items` collection, just as you can for a regular `ComboBox` control.